# Run script full screen in terminal

Tags: 14.04, bash, lubuntu, scripts

How do I get a bash script to run in full screen when it's executed or how can I change the terminal size if I can't make it full screen?

Answer (score 4):

"Fullscreen" isn't a bash concept at all, it's down to your terminal emulator window and X.

However if you're scripting, you can tell X to add a fullscreen hint to a client. I most applications this will work. I've tested with Terminator and I've no reason to suspect it won't work with Gnome Terminal:

```
# set fullscreen on startup
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,fullscreen

# ... do your stuff ...

# and before you quit
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,fullscreen
```

---

With regard to keeping this at a minimum footprint, the only way I've found to do this is to launch another terminal. Unfortunately `lxterminal` doesn't have a fullscreen launch option so you could either [hack through the OpenBox settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46195/how-to-make-lxterminals-open-maximized-in-lubuntu-11-04) (beurgh) or just fall back to `xterm`:

```
xterm -fullscreen -hold -e ./anotherscript.sh
```

Yeah, I'm suggesting launching another terminal. If you're shipping this with a launcher of sorts, you can avoid needing a secondary script.

`xterm` doesn't adhere to standard fonts or anything like that though you can configure almost everything through command line arguments (see `man xterm` for a riveting read).

Comment: I appreciate it but wmctrl isn't on Lubuntu

Comment: Is installing it (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`) too much?

Comment: Ha no but I'm sending this script to many people on different distros on Linux and I just want it to work right out of the gate.

Comment: That's understandable. It's adding more work for you but you could package it into a .deb that depended on the `wmctrl` package. That would also save on people putting it in the wrong places (and needing to set permissions). Might be less work in the long run.

Comment: I'll download Lubuntu and see what's available. There's probably something openbox specific that'll work.

Comment: @Roboman1723 there is no terminal/tty agnostic way to force a fullscreen because the shell must be aware of the terminal properties, which is what `wmctrl` does, it is best to stick to a tool that is compatible with the largest amount of window managers and require/suggest your users to use it as a dependency, `wmctrl` is *not* ubuntu specific, and works with a large number of WM/DE's ([it works with  KDE,Gnome/unity Gnome/metacity, L/XFCE, etc.](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) and is available as a package on Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, Arch, Gentoo, Slackware, and RHEL among others.

Answer (score 1):

Press F11 to make the terminal full screen. If you always want it full screen, you need to edit the .desktop file:

Create a new file, via gedit or similar in `/.local/share/applications`. Call it `fsterminal.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Full Screen Terminal
Comment=Open Terminal full screen
Exec=gnome-terminal --full-screen
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: Is there a way to force terminal to run full screen in a script?

Comment: So you are running a script, and it opens `gnome-terminal`? Yeah, add  the options `--full-screen`

Comment: I saw that and put it in like this: 
`gnome-terminal --full-screen`

It still doesn't launch full screen

Comment: Does it from terminal (i.e. if you open one then run `gnome-terminal --full-screen` does it open in in full screen mode?

Comment: No it doesn't because Lubuntu uses XFCE terminal not gnome

Comment: @Roboman1723 Lubuntu normally uses LXTerminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if [xterm escape sequences](http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html) work for your terminal, e.g.

- `echo -ne "\e[8;XXX;YYYt"` resizes terminal to show XXX columns and YYY rows
- `echo -ne "\e[9;1t"` maximizes the terminal window (doesn't work for me)
- ...

On my ubuntu 14.04 machine running unity, `echo -ne "\e[8;200;200"` resizes the terminal beyond screen edges effectively maximizing the window.

Comment: Didn't seem to work on Lubuntu, thank you though.